# Django movie and director relation. Movie is not attached to the director

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

I'm making a model, consisting of a movie and a director. When I create a movie, I want the movie to be automatically owned by the director I selected but it's not working.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    imdb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)     
    director = models.ForeignKey('Director', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Movies'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, related_name='movies', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Directors'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am creating a new movie using django-admin page. for instance;[django-admin creating movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChJOn.png)

However the movie is not automatically added to the director.
[Director](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgZE5.png)

I also want a movie to belong to only one director.
How can I do these. I will be very glad if you can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's already the case *without* any need for an extra relation. Indeed, you define this as:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    imdb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    director = models.ForeignKey(
        'Director', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='movies'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Movies'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Directors'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If you then assign a director `D1` to a move `M1`, you can query the movies of the director with:

```
D1.movies.all()
```

In the modeladmin you can also display the movies when editing a `Director` through an *inline*, for example a [**`TabularInline`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline):

```
from django.contrib import admin


class MovieInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Movie


@admin.register(Director)
class DirectorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    inlines = [
        MovieInline,
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did as you said. I created a new movie[image: like this]

But It is not attached here as a list named movies [image: director]

Here are my codes:
serializers.py

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['movie_id']


class DirectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Director
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class DirectorListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Director.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = serializers.DirectorSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.BasicAuthentication]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Director.objects.all()
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
        if name is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)
        return queryset


class MovieListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MovieSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.BasicAuthentication]
    filter_backends = [django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['category', 'director']
    search_fields = ['category__name', 'director__name', 'name',]
    ordering_fields = ['production_year', 'imdb', 'duration']
```

Comment: You should *not* define the `ManyToManyField`...